# Installing edubuntu 13-04 on usb without downloading any other iso's than what I already have

Tags: installation, wubi, live-usb

I have the Edubuntu-13.04-dvd-amd64 iso, and the wubi installer, but can't get the installer to use the iso and put edubuntu on my 14 GB flashdrive. Is it possible to install edubuntu on my flashdrive using just the files that I already have without downloading any others?(internet is slow)  Note that I got wubi on a 4 GB flashdrive using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.3.7   Also note that I used saucy-desktop-i386 iso to download wubi.

Comment: What does the logfile in the `%TEMP%` directory say?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Edubuntu liveCD and install it to your flash drive. You can run the liveCD in VirtualBox without having to burn the disk image.